# sed how to escape " ( and special characters escaping

Tags: bash, sed

I am trying to do the following pattern replacement with sed, but it keeps telling me it cannot find the pattern. I dont know the right combination of escaping to make it work.

```
sed -i -e s_('DB_SOURCE', 'demo')_('DB_SOURCE', 'local')_ sedTest
```

Comment: You probably need to put quotes around the entire sed script, and then escape the quotes inside the script. It would probably also be a good idea to choose a different character as delimiter than `_` because it appears inside the pattern. (I'm also not sure of the correct solution, that's why this is only a comment and not an answer)

Comment: There are two levels of interpretation, which makes this hard to understand for newbies. You need to escape many of these characters from the shell, but then also some of them need to be escaped from `sed` after that. But for your specific case, lnian's answer is spot on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to either escape all the meta-characters involved the `(`, `)`, white-space character and `'` (single-quotes), also change the separator to `#` over `_`

```
sed -e s#\(\'DB_SOURCE\',\ \'demo\'\)#\(\'DB_SOURCE\',\ \'local\'\)# file
```

Or use the entire substitution inside double-quotes(`"`). Ensure the search or replacement text does not contain a `$`, because the variable could be interpolated under double-quotes. In such a case just add a escape to it (`\$`)

```
sed "s#('DB_SOURCE', 'demo')#('DB_SOURCE', 'local')#" file
```

---

As tripleee points out in the comments there are two levels of interpretation here, the one by sed, and by the shell itself. In the shell, everything between single quotes is interpreted literally, except for single quotes themselves. Sed uses basic regular expressions. In a BRE, the characters `$.*[\]^` need to be quoted by preceding them by a backslash.